# PHP Centos Webstatic and Imagick

Tags: centos, php

I was trying to install php 5.4 on Centos 6.3 and I decided to go with the webstatic version. I've tried to to install imagick using the followng commands

```
pecl install imagick
yum install php54w-pecl-imagick
yum install php54w-imagick
```

But each to no avail. Is there a way to install imagick using php54w?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The pecl package throws an error when using autodetect and the other two packages don't exist.

Comment: Webtatic has since added the imagick extension, so your first yum command `yum install php54w-pecl-imagick` would work

Answer (score 1):

You can use IUS Community repo - http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/. But first of all you need to uninstall previously installed php packages. And the execute the following commands

```
# rpm --import http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY
# rpm -ivh http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.el6.noarch.rpm
# yum install php54-pecl-imagick
```

P.S. I assumed that you have used x64 arch

Comment: FWIW on CentOS 5 the RPM is found at: `http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.el5.noarch.rpm`